# SQL - Get all dates between Current day and start and end of week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff, dateadd

I am trying to set the start day to Saturday

```
SET DATEFIRST 6 -- Sets start day to Saturday
```

And then get all the GameDate between the start of the week and the end of the week. But it needs to be done with the current day. For instance: if the current day is thursday and the end of the week is Friday I don't want to do this:

```
DECLARE @StartWeek datetime Set @StartWeek = DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), -5))
DECLARE @EndWeek datetime Set @EndWeek = DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), 1))
```

Because this will make it that the next 5 days will get shown.
And If the CurrentDay is on Thursday I don't want the next 5 days to get shown. Just the GameDates from every week.

This is what I got so far:

```
DECLARE @DateTable Table (DateofWeek Date) -- Creates table
DECLARE @DateToday Date SELECT DAY(GETDATE()) 'Current Day' -- Gets current date

DECLARE @StartWeek datetime Set @StartWeek = DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), -5)) --This is the part thats wrong
DECLARE @EndWeek datetime Set @EndWeek = DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), 1)) --This is the part thats wrong

SET DATEFIRST 6 -- Sets start day to Saturday


SELECT DATEDIFF ( DAY, @DateToday, @EndWeek) AS Diffrence_End
SELECT DATEDIFF ( DAY, @DateToday, @StartWeek) AS Diffrence_Start
    FROM @DateTable

WHILE @DateToday >= @EndWeek AND @DateToday <= @StartWeek -- Shows all gameDates between StartWeek and Endweek
BEGIN   
    SELECT DATEDIFF ( DAY, @DateToday, @EndWeek)
    Insert Into @DateTable



SELECT * 
    FROM @DateTable
END;
```

Some of the Query is probably wrong, especially the last part.

I hope I made myself clear enough, if there are any questions please don't hesitate to ask me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look:

> ```
> -- Sets start day to Saturday
> SET DATEFIRST 6 
>
> -- Creates table
> DECLARE @DateTable Table ([DateofWeek] date); 
>
> -- StartDate = DATEPART(DW, ... ) = 1
> DECLARE @StartDate date; 
> SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) - 1) * -1, GETDATE());
>
> -- EndDate = StartDate + 6 days
> DECLARE @EndDate date;
> SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, 6, @StartDate);
>
> -- Generates table values
> DECLARE @CurrentDate date;
> SET @CurrentDate = @StartDate;
>
> WHILE @CurrentDate <= @EndDate
> BEGIN
>     INSERT INTO @DateTable ([DateofWeek]) VALUES (@CurrentDate);
>     SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate);
> END
>
> --Check it
> SELECT *, DATENAME(dw, DateOfWeek) as Name FROM @DateTable;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> DateofWeek          | Name     
> :------------------ | :--------
> 18/03/2017 00:00:00 | Saturday 
> 19/03/2017 00:00:00 | Sunday   
> 20/03/2017 00:00:00 | Monday   
> 21/03/2017 00:00:00 | Tuesday  
> 22/03/2017 00:00:00 | Wednesday
> 23/03/2017 00:00:00 | Thursday 
> 24/03/2017 00:00:00 | Friday
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=bdf10253a3842b2026ae298a8ba60a3f)*